# Change qpid Protocol version number using c++ api

Tags: c++, rabbitmq, amqp, qpid

While running through the qpid c++ api tutorial I ran into "Session ended by peer with amqp:internal-error" which i assume is because of different versions of the qpid api and my broker (Rabbitmq).

I have changed the rabbitmq to use protocol 1.0, but it looks like qpid defaults to 0-10.  I have found a bunch of articles saying I should move up to version 1.0 of the api, but I have not been able to find out how.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution, when creating connection you can set protocol there, though i think you may need qpid-proton installed as well.

```
Connection connection("rabbitmq-serv:5672","{protocol: 'amqp1.0'}");
```

It still gets failures, but rabbitmq seems to acknowledge that it exists

Also qpid-proton seems to connect to rabbitmq no problem, using the amqp1.0 by default